# Change in entropy in reversible and irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

Let's take a process with constant pressure in ideal gas for example. in reversible process
$dS=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{C_pdT}{T}$

Assuming constant specific heat capacity, the result  is state function, so is the entropy. Then we learned that $dS=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{C_pdT}{T}$ is true for irreversible process too. But to prove it we used the fact that in reversible process $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$. How is that logically possible?

Comment: The only way we know of to determine the entropy change from an initial state to a final state of a closed system using classical thermodynamics is to calculate the integral of dq/T for a reversible path between these states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But to prove it we used the fact that in reversible process
> $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$. How is that logically possible?

I think you misunderstand. The entropy change is ***defined*** for a reversible transfer of heat, but applies to any process, reversible or not, and whether or not any heat transfer is involved. Since entropy is a state function independent of the process, one can replace any actual irreversible process between two states with any convenient reversible path between the same two states and calculate the entropy change using the definition of entropy. Note the reversible path need not bear any resemblance to the actual process.

Although the change in entropy of the *system* is the same for a reversible and irreversible process, the total change in entropy of the *system plus its surroundings* is not. For a reversible process it is zero. For an irreversible process it is greater than zero.

For the reversible isobaric expansion process the system must be brought into contact with an infinite series of thermal reservoirs, ranging between the initial and final temperature, with the temperature of each reservoir being infinitesimally greater than the preceding and always infinitesimally greater than the temperature of the system. Thus the change in entropy of the system is

$$\Delta S_{sys}=\int_1^2\frac{C_{p}dT}{T}=C_{p}\ln\frac {T_{2}}{T_1}\tag {1}$$

Since surroundings is always in thermal equilibrium with the system throughout the process, and since the only difference is heat is leaving the surroundings (is negative), the heat transfer is reversible and the change in entropy of the surroundings is

$$\Delta S_{surr}=-C_{p}\ln\frac {T_{2}}{T_1}\tag{2}$$

from which it follows

$$\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}=0\tag{3}$$

Now consider instead the system being placed in contact with a single thermal reservoir in the surroundings of temperature equal to the temperature of the equilibrium state. Due to the finite temperature difference between the system and surroundings, heat transfer is irreversible. The entropy change of the system is the same, but for the surroundings it is

$$\Delta S_{surr}=-\int_1^2 \frac{Q}{T_2}= -\int_1^2 \frac{C_{p}(T_{2}-T_{1})}{T_2}\tag{4}$$

From which it can be shown for any $T_2$ and $T_1$

$$\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}=C_{p}\ln\frac {T_{2}}{T_1}-\int_1^2 \frac{C_{p}(T_{2}-T_{1})}{T_2}\gt 0\tag{5}$$

> So isn't it correct to write
> $=_{}/+_{}$ in irreversible?
> instead of just $=_{}/$

It's not correct. Instead, it should be written without the $rev$ subscript for $Q$ as:

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T_{B}}+dS_{generated}\tag{6}$$

where $\delta Q$ is the differential amount of heat flowing into the system from its surroundings (through the boundary with its surroundings), $T_B$ is the temperature at the boundary through which the heat is flowing, which is not necessarily the same as the temperature within the system, and $dS_{generated}$ is the differential amount of entropy generated within the system as a result of irreversible component of the heat transfer and any irreversible work that is done.

In equation (6) it is helpful to think of $\frac{\delta Q}{T_B}$ as the differential entropy ***change*** as a result of entropy ***transfer*** and $dS_{generated}$ as the differential amount of entropy ***generated*** within the system during the process due to irreversible heat transfer and/or irreversible work.

For a reversible process path, the amount of entropy generated within the system is zero, so the entropy change for such a path is simply

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}\tag{7}$$

where $T$ is the temperature throughout the system and not just at the boundary, as the system is always in thermal equilibrium with the surroundings in order for the heat transfer to be reversible.

Combining equations (6) and (7) we can determine the differential amount of entropy generated for the irreversible process as

$$dS_{generated}=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}-\frac{\delta Q}{T_{B}}\tag{8}$$

EXAMPLE:

As an example of the application of equations (6) through (8) consider the reversible and irreversible isobaric processes previously introduced.
Let $T_{1}=300 K$ and  $T_{2}=600 K$.

From Eq (1) the change in entropy of the system for the reversible process, where the temperature within system is always the same as at the boundary with the surroundings, is

$$\Delta S_{sys}=C_{p}\ln\frac{600}{300}=+0.69 C_{p}\tag{9}$$

since this is the same change in entropy as the irreversible process, we can equate the result of eq (9) with integral form of the right hand side of eq (6)

$$0.69 C_{p}=\int_1^2\frac{C_{p}dT}{T_{B}}+S_{generated}\tag{10}$$

For the irreversible process the temperature at the boundary is constant and equals that of the single 600 K thermal reservoir. Therefore $T_{B}=600 K$  and $C_{p}dT=C_{p}(T_{2}-T_{1})$. Eq (10) becomes

$$0.69 C_{p}=\frac{C_{p}(600-300)}{600}+S_{generated}\tag{11}$$

$$0.69 C_{p}=0.5 C_{p}+S_{generated}\tag {12}$$

from which it follows

$$S_{generated}=+0.19 C_{p}\tag{13}$$

To summarize, for the irreversible isobaric process

$$\Delta S_{sys}=0.5 C_{p} + 0.19 C_{p}=0.69 C_{p}\tag{14}$$

Where

$0.5C_{p}$ = the entropy transferred to the system from the surroundings.

$0.19 C_{p}$ = the entropy generated within the system due to irreversible heat transfer.

$0.69 C_{p}$ = the total entropy change of the system

Hope this helps.

Comment: So isn't it correct to write $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}+dS_{generated}$ in irreversible? instead of just $dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$

Comment: @Dor No, that's not correct. I will update my answer to explain why.

Comment: @Dor See update to my answer. Hope it helps.